# heroku deployment busted, operational error

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-deployment, operationalerror

I am getting error message after deploying to heroku (in my web browser):

```
OperationalError at /accounts/register/
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

In `settings.py` I have:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydata',
    'USER': [a name],
    'PASSWORD': [a password],
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I see some whining in heroku logs of:

```
2015-04-25T07:53:35.555555+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=client at=error code=H18 desc="Request Interrupted" method=GET path="/accounts/register/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=[long string] fwd="43.55.555.555" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=119ms status=503 bytes=13000

2015-04-25T07:56:49.555555+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-04-25T07:56:52.555555+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
```

but it does more after that. The last series of messages ends with:

```
2015-04-25T13:30:06:555555+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

and 6 summaries, with statuses `301`, `404`, `404`, `292`, `404`, `404`

My `wsgi.py` is unchanged:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "dating_site.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I even added the full path in my proc:

`web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi --pythonpath ../mysite --log-file -`

By `../mysite` here I was saying the main `mysite` directory w/ `settings.py`, `wsgi.py`, and a few other goodies.

When I go to the webpage of `myapponheroku/accounts` I get a pretty index page, but when I click on "register" I get the error at the top of the entry...what really baffles me? `accounts/login` renders a form with a `csrf_token` required...it loads just fine! The `accounts/register` renders a form with of course csrf required...it grumbles about `could not connect to server: Connection refused`. Interestingly enough, attempting to actually login on the login page with my testing username and password yields literally the same error if you replace `accounts/register` with `accounts/login` from the top of the page ('operational error' yada yada)

What can cause/fix a problem this strange? Thank you django stars,

Cody

Comment: I believe the issue is ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ ] in settings.py....my app name was changed to "cody-my-app.herokuapp.com"...do I add 'cody-my-app' or the entire string to ALLOWED_HOSTS, and do I have to git push heroku master each time I make changes to see them work on heroku? This is my first serious heroku usage

Comment: The problem is worse now. Following additional instructions on heroku, I added to wsgi.py:

`import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "dating_site.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())`

Comment: In settings.py I added:

in settings.py I added:

`import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirpath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)`

Comment: should it be "BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))"?

Comment: I should mention with these changes, the app will not even load anymore, although without the settings Heroku.com recommends I at least got stuff working:

`Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.`

`If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah each time you make a change and want to see it live in Heroku you need to do `git push heroku master`.  As long as you have an outgoing change set.